# PHP inline statement using ternary logic operator "?:"

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I have a var which return `TRUE` or `FALSE`. how do I use ternary logic to return the string

"YES" if **$var1** is TRUE and

"NO" if **$var1** is FALSE ?

```
$Var1 = TRUE; /*dynamic value*/
$status = ($Var1 == true ? $Var1:"NO");
```

Thank you.

Comment: `($Var1 == true ?  "YES" : "NO")`?

Comment: Or more concise… `$status = $Var1 ? 'YES' : 'NO';`. `== true` and `()` is all redundant.

Comment: great! .Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$status = $Var1 ? 'YES' : 'NO';
```

You cannot go shorter than that :)

you do not need neither () nor == TRUE since if $var1 returns true if it is not null, 0 or false.

Comment: great..Thank you. very educative and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$status = ($Var1 == true ? "YES":"NO");
```

Answer (score -1):

$status = ( $var1 === true ) ? "YES" : "NO";